# 404 errors with Virtual Host in VPS Server

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I'm trying to create a virtual host in my vps server but I'm receiving "HTTP Status 404 - Not found".
My Virtual Host:

`vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/demonstracao.itcmedbr.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName demonstracao.itcmedbr.com
        ServerAlias www.demonstracao.itcmedbr.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/demonstracao.itcmedbr.com/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/demonstracao.itcmedbr.com/log/error.log

        CustomLog /var/www/demonstracao.itcmedbr.com/log/requests.log combined


        <Directory /var/www/demonstracao.itcmedbr.com/html>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://IPaddr:8081/demonstracao.itcmedbr.com/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://IPaddr:8081/demonstracao.itcmedbr.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPass               /demonstracao.itcmedbr.com      http://localhost:8081/demonstracao.itcmedbr.com
ProxyPassReverse        /demonstracao.itcmedbr.com      http://localhost:8081/demonstracao.itcmedbr.com
```

I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: "HTTP Status 404 - Not found" means resource you try to get by url doesnt exists

Comment: Why the two line in `http.conf`? Instead replace `IPaddr:8081` with `localhost:8081` in the `VirtualHost` config file. Assuming the subfolder `demonstracao.itcmedbr.com` exist im the document root for localhost:8081.

Comment: Hi, localhost generate the same problem. The content of DocumentRoot is a deploy of java war, this war have JSPs, Servlet, MySQL db access, Javascript.